# Cloth sim shirt gets stuck and unstable on characters under arms

Tags: mesh, rigging, physics, cloth-simulation

My cloth sim shirt keeps getting stuck under my character's arm pit like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWxkY.jpg

[image]

Since the cloth is constantly stuck there it won't settle and the shirt won't stop vibrating. This issue only seems to happen in the underarms.

I've tried messing around with the collision distances on the body and the shirt, but nothing seems to make a difference. I also tried applying my sub surf modifier thinking more vertices would help, but nada.

What can I do to stop the cloth from bunching up like this?

Thanks in advance!!

The blend file can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iEDXcQhlnu-DkZcLB5veaC1lim_F3igS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From what I see you should apply the scale and rotation of your shirt, remove the Collision, parent it With Automatic Weights to the armature, put the modifiers in this order: Armature/CLoth/Solidify, create a Pin Group, maybe lower the topology... Here is a good tuto on clothes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

Comment: @moonboots I followed your advice and the cloth is still getting stuck and unstable in the under arms of the character. Were you able fix this on your end?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you should apply the scale and rotation of your shirt, remove the *Collision*, parent it *With Automatic Weights* to the armature, put the modifiers in this order: *Armature/Cloth/Solidify*, create a *Pin* group, maybe lower the topology... [Here](https://youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg) is a good tuto on clothes.

I've made all these changes and some other small tweakings and here is what I get, but Blender *Cloth* is still really tricky to use imho:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: are you able to tell me what small adjustments you made for the sleeves to work that smoothly? Where did you make the pin group?

Comment: please download the file, you'll see the pin group, it's still not pefect but anyway as i said, i think it's hard to set

Comment: Sounds good, thanks so much for your help @moonboots !